Opposite of @Nationalized hibernate annotation
I am looking for the opposite of @nationalized hibernate annotation. When specifying spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data =true nationalization is the default behaviour, but how can I create an exception if I have some column that is not nationalized?

(Someone nominated this question for a close as "needs details or clarity", but did not add a comment to that effect that the OP can see.) My guess is that someone not familiar with Hybernate data categorizations would like a to see more information, possibly code snippets illustrating a class and current mapping attribute usage.

I have no experience with hibernate. A quick dive into the documentation did not reveal any obvious @nonnationalized or @LocaleType attribute candidates, but I did find the @column annotation that might serve your needs. Perhaps @Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(MAX)") or similar might work. Might have portability issues if that is a concern.

You can annotate the columns which should not be nationalized with @JdbcType(VarcharJdbcType.class). The annotation allows you to specify an explicit JdbcType for a column and overwrites the default nationalization behaviour defined by hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data.
Tested with Hibernate 6.2.26.
